# What to do about a particular Spam Only user

Tags: discussion, spam, new-users

I noticed this morning that a new user, [user85896](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85896/), which was created "today", has posted three answers that are obviously spam and one that I flagged as link-only, which should probably have been spam as well.

I don't have the rep to do anything about this, but I'm posting it here so someone with a decent amount of rep can take the appropriate action, if it is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Status: Completed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I wasn't sure if this was the correct thing to do or if there was some other way I should handle it.

Comment: A meta post will work, but generally speaking, since obvious spam doesn't really need a lot of meta discussion, 'flagging' the post would have a more effective way of letting someone know in a timely manner. Regards.

Comment: @Mark Flagging for spam gets it handled the fastest...

Comment: Got it. Thanks @bmike.